# IIS Server - Out of memory

Tags: iis-7

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 with 128Gb of memory and INtel Xeon E5 2650 v3. 
Any time the memory usage for the App Pool goes close to 2.4Gb (according to Task Manager) I'm starting to get Out of memory exceptions and I have to recycle the app pool. 
The `Virtual Memory Limit` is set to 0 for this app pool.

The overall server memory usage is always under 25%.

How do I increase the app pool memory limit?

How do I make it so that is not running as 32-bit application? Is this happening because I enabled `Enable 32-bit applications`? I actually need this because I have a managed assembly which is 32-bit only.

What is other solution for this? Don't say check your code, I need for certain cases that memory usage amount.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

32 bit applications can address a maximum of 2 GB. Also see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: yeah, I know that, so it looks like the only solution is to remove that 32bit library and disable 32bit support for the app pool

Comment: You could try to migrate the library, check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973190.aspx